# I can't open my admin panel by using xampp

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost, wp-admin

I'm using Xampp for localhost and I created a website in the last night but now in the morning i can't access my wordpress localhost admin panel. When I try to open it they show me this type of message-

**Object not found!**

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

**Error 404**

localhost
Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.1

Comment: What's the url that you typed?, Don't forget, in the XAMPP control panel to start the Apache and MySQL modules.

Comment: I also start Apache and mySQL and my url is - http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin

Comment: Try login, wp-admin.php or admin instead of wp-admin. And did you install any plugins that change the default endpoint for the login page?

Answer (score 0):

***I get my answer or solution*** actually I did mistake of my directory folder name. I didn't write my directory folder name in url. I was type url like this 
--------------------------> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin
But my true url is this --> http://localhost/wordpress/portfolio-one/wp-admin/